# How do I get the selected Bootstrap pill in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using vertical pills (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-pills) and was wondering how on the AngularJS side I would keep track of which pill is selected?

Each pill has it's own set of input fields and based on whichever pill is selected, I need to get information from the input fields. I've searched online and I can't seem to find a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having Angular *detect* which pill is active (a jQuery way of thinking), you should have Angular *set* which tab is active.

I could write a lot about how to make Angular work with your existing Bootstrap setup (basically, have Bootstrap's "active" class bound to variables in your Angular scope/controller using ng-class, and handle the clicks with ng-click), but what you're describing sounds a lot like [(Angular) UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)'s vertical tabsets with type "pills". Even though UI Bootstrap is roughly a port of Bootstrap's components into the Angular model, it's not exactly trivial to switch over. But since your use case sounds like it's pretty involved, I think it would be worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Create a directive. On the directive template add the pills and on the link function of your directive add the event listener to the container of the pills (event delegation) so that you can track which pill was selected and change your logic according to it.

Added a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/r2MboEw6jCxeMAjyPQ7s?p=preview) whit the basis.

```
  angular.module('pills', [])
          .directive('pills', directiveFactory);

  function directiveFactory () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: link,
      templateUrl: 'pills.html'
    };

    function link (scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('click', 'nav-pills', click);

      function click (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
         console.log(event.target, 'event is an object');
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: How would I know if Home was selected versus Profile or Messages?

Comment: The event object has a property target this the element that was clicked

Comment: So is that event.object or something? Because I don't see that option.

Comment: the event parameter is an object. I changed the example so you can see it. `event.target`